# How to access to a function whose access modifier is protected and exists in a class that inherits from another class in c#?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, protected, access-modifiers

```
public class a
{
    protected virtual int mult(int x)
    {
        return x * x;
    }
}

public class b : a
{
    protected override int mult(int x) { return x * x * x; }
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        b jack = new b();
        int v = jack.mult(5);    // error

        // so how can I access mult() in the main class without changing the access modifier to public ??????
    }
}
```

How to access a function whose access modifier is protected and exists in a class that inherits from another class in c#?

Comment: If you understand what `protected` means then you know that you can't. `protected` members are not accessible from outside the type.

Comment: Change protected to public.

Comment: What is the context of the problem? *Why* do you need to call this `protected` method *without* changing the access modifier, which would exactly solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `mult` function is declared as `protected` in both class `a` and class `b`, which means that it can only be accessed by code within the class or its derived classes. Since `b` is a derived class of `a`, the `mult` function is accessible to code within `b`.

If you want to access the `mult` function from a class other than `b` or `a` subclass of `b`, you will need to change the access modifier to the `public` or provide a public method in `b` or `a` subclass of `b` that calls the `mult` function.

In this case you are doing all this in the `Main` method which is in other class than `a` or `b`.